# Intent.EXTRA_CC not working with Android's GMail 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open mail client using intent. I want the CC and BCC field to be filled. This was working fine until recently I noticed that GMail 4.2 is ignoring my CC and BCC fields. This is working great on Gingerbread though. Here's the code that I'm using.

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "a@b.com", "b@c.com"} );
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] { "thisisacc@gmail.com", "anothercc@c.com"});
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[] {"bcc@gmail.com", "anotherbcc@gmail.com"});
mailIntent.setType("text/html");
mailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(mailIntent);
```

This does open GMail's Compose screen but the CC field and BCC field are not shown. The more confusing part is, when you send it anyway, it works! It actually sends it to the CC and BCC email ids. It is just the UI that doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure an email in "email app"(not gmail) and test it. That might be bug in gmail app.

Or did u test gmail app by sending a mail(manually) adding cc and bcc?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in GMail. I tried with other mail clients, even the Yahoo! Mail app for Android. it works fine. I've mailed the Gmail support team now. Waiting for their reply.

Comment: It was fixed for me, after gmail got 4.3 update (Try updating the gmail app)

Comment: and 8 years later the bug is back - GMail refused to respect my EXTRA_BCC